# Strange behaviour while trying to add element to a JPA entity list : only the first element persist

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, arraylist, glassfish, eclipselink

sorry for my English in advance.
I trying to add elements in an entity list and **only the first element stay in this list**.

Here an example :

```
Project project = project_facade.find(1L);
Machine machine = machine_facade.find(1L);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setName("Test "+i);

    test.setProject(project);
    test.setMachine(machine);

    project.getTestList().add(test);
    machine.getTestList().add(test);
}

project.getMachineList().add(machine);
machine.getProjectList().add(project);

project_facade.edit(project);
```

After this, in the database, the project and the machine are linked correctly (through a mapping table), but the Test table contains only the record "Test 0" (the project_id field and machine_id field are correct).

I don't understand why it's work for the first element only...

Thanks for your help !!!

Project entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Machine> machineList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL *SOLUTION : ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER* )
    private List<Test> testList;

    //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Machine Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Machine implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinTable(name = "project_machine", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "machine", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Project> projectList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "machine",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Test> testList;

    //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Test Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Project project;

    @JoinColumn(name = "machine", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Machine machine;

    //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Then all my facades extends AbstractFacade where edit method is:

```
public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us both entities as well as the implementation of `project_facade.edit()`

Comment: Of course, done

Comment: implementation of `getTestList()`s ? should the 1st element be actually `Test 0` ?

Comment: getTestList() is just a getter and, yes, the first element is "Test 0", sorry for my mistake, it's not "Test 1"

Comment: what is your environment: persistence provider, container where you run this ?

Comment: I use JSF on Glassfish 4.1.1 with EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) on a MySQL db

Comment: ok, since with tomee & openjpa your code seem to work fine. only difference was that i used `em.merge()` in my test case directly without any `AbstractFacade` implementation

Comment: Does it works if you remove cascade annotation on test entity ?

Comment: WTF ?! It works in debug mode !!?? If i ran the loop step by step all elements are persisted !

Comment: What version of EclipseLink are you using? Seems like a bug with change detection, so that the later additions to the list, since they don't have an id set yet, are appearing to be the same entity rather than being treated as the new instances you intended. An alternate workaround would be to call project.getTestList().size() prior to your loop to trigger fetching the collection, allowing you to keep it as lazy in the rest of your code.  Another would be to disable change tracking: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer !!!!! I have added "fetch = FetchType.EAGER" on the OneToMany annotation of Project entity !